# The method getId() is undefined for the type ClassName

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I am learning Spring boot and got stuck in a problem. I have created an Expense class as following:

```
    @AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name="expense")
public class Expense {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    private Instant expensedate;

    private String description;

    private String location;

    @ManyToOne
    private Category category;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    private User user;
}
```

Now I am trying to create a controller to add/delete the Expense objects. Following method is for creating Expense object:

```
@PostMapping("/expenses")
ResponseEntity<Expense> createExpense(@Valid @RequestBody Expense expense) throws URISyntaxException{
    Expense result = expenseRepository.save(expense);
    return ResponseEntity.created(new URI("/api/expense" + result.getId())).body(result);
}
```

But here in this method I am getting following error:

> The method getId() is undefined for the type Expanse

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did You have install lombok plugin in your IDE?

If you are using Eclipse:

[Lombok download page](https://projectlombok.org/download)

If you are using Intellij find the plugin there.

Comment: I am using STS, how do I install lombok in there?

Comment: Download from that link and execute. It will scan for the STS folder, if It not found you specify manually and then click Install.

Comment: Done, I have installed it, do I need to import anything now? The error is still there?

Comment: ok got it, I added @Getter above the id and I am now able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "@GeneratedValue" below "@Id".

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Setter @Getter` annotations

Answer (score 0):

If the above methods like:

1. installing Lombak
2. restarting Eclipse
3. Clean/Build the project
   still show the error, try a forth thing:
4. I deleted the last character of @Data and used intellisense to put it back. Eclipse refreshed the project and the getId() was gone.